# C# Automapper conditional mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, automapper

I am using nhibernate to map elements from one object to another. However, one of the elements in my complex objects, needs to have a condition set in order for the destination object element to have a value set accordingly.

To explain in detail

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<OneObject, AnotherObject>()
 .ForMember( 
     destination => destination.complexelement, 
       option => option.MapFrom(source=> source.value == enumValue.ToString() 
        ? new object( {Id 123 }) 
        : new object ({ Id 567 }))
```

So, you can see that I want to set a nested object on the destination object based upon a value from the source object to create an object and save it to the destination element. The example code above I have tried, but it is throwing an error saying I can't use a string on a lambda expression.

Does anyone know how I can set an object based upon a condition?

Thanks

Comment: What's `enumValue`? And what's the actual error text?

Comment: emumvalue is just there for comparison. Error message I have given you

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. Unfortunately it is based on AutoMapper 6.1.1. Hope you can use this version. Because I didn't know your class structure, I created simple test classes, but you should be abled to transfer the sample to your scenario.

```
OneObject oo = new OneObject();
oo.value = "B";
Testenum enumValue = Testenum.A;

Mapper.Initialize(a => a.CreateMap<OneObject, AnotherObject>()
    .ForMember(
        destination => destination.complexelement,
        option => option.MapFrom(source => source.value == enumValue.ToString()
            ? 123
            : 567)));

AnotherObject ao = Mapper.Map<OneObject, AnotherObject>(oo);
```

Test classes and enum

```
class OneObject
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

class AnotherObject
{
    public object complexelement { get; set; }
}

enum Testenum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```